# Maps JavaScript API で、アプリケーションの制限 を IPアドレス にした時だけエラーになる

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

PHP と JavaScript を使用して地図を表示しているのですが、
Maps JavaScript API で、アプリケーションの制限 を IPアドレス にした時だけエラーになります。HTTP リファラー で設定するとエラーになりません。

[IPアドレスの制限だけではうまくいかない](http://forum.basercms.net/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=3085&forum=8&post_id=10620)のリンク先で
[位置情報取得も、Javascriptに変更した](https://github.com/baserproject/basercms/commit/0587cf6f88286f00baeb67baeb9a2f88bc400dd8)と書いてあるのですが、どういう意味ですか？

アプリケーションの制限 を IPアドレス にすると、何が影響を受けるのですか？
・PHPコード？
・JavaScriptコード？
・それとも両方？？

BaserCMSもリンク先コードも使用していないのですが、PHPとJavaScriptを使用しているので何かヒントになるかもしれない、と思い質問しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIキーに利用制限をかけるということですか？

JavaScriptは閲覧ユーザーのPCで実行されるため、
IP制限を許可する場合は閲覧する人のIPを登録する必要があります。

WebにGoogle Mapを載せるのであれば、
制限はドメインにしたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: 閲覧者IPを登録するのですね。サーバのIPアドレスを登録してそのサイトのみAPI実行許可する仕様なのかと思っていました